# malloc Assertion Failed

Tags: c, malloc

I wrote a program that takes lexicographically ordered strings and performs the next lexicographically ordered permutation of those strings, ex:

```
strings: a b c d
a b c d
a b d c
a c b d
a c d b
a d b c
a d c b
...
d c b a
```

If a string is repeated you gotta make sure steps aren't, ex:

```
strings: a bc bc
NOT GOOD   GOOD
a bc bc    a bc bc
a bc bc    bc a bc
bc a bc    bc bc a
bc bc a
bc bc a
bc a bc
```

This programs works great for n number of strings up to 5, but it has to work up to 9.
On 6 however, the program aborts and I don't know how to fix it. I know what the problem is, at least I think I do, but this is already long enough, here's the code and the errors I get when running the program normally, with pwngdb, and valgrind.

****SPOILERS**** This problem is from HackerRank, if you have yet to figure it out refrain from looking at this, answers, and comments.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void 
swap(char **s, int a, int b) 
{
    char *t;
    t = malloc(11 * sizeof(char));

    t = s[a];
    s[a] = s[b];
    s[b] = t;
}

void 
sort(char **s, int d, int n) 
{
    int i, k;

    for(k = 0; k <= n; k++)
        for(i = d + 1; i < n; i++)
            if(strcmp(s[i-1], s[i]) > 0)
                swap(s, i-1, i);
}

void 
to_string(char **s, char *t, int n) 
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if(i == 0)
            strcpy(t, s[i]);
        else
            strcat(t, s[i]);
}

int next_permutation(int n, char **s)
{
    /**
    * Complete this method
    * Return 0 when there is no next permutation and 1 otherwise
    * Modify array s to its next permutation
    */
    int i;

    static unsigned int *p, p_step, *m, lock;

    if(!lock) {
        p       = calloc(n + 1, sizeof(int));
        p_step  = 1;
        m       = malloc(n + 1 * sizeof(int));
        m[0]    = 0;
        for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            m[i] = n;

        p[0]    = 1;
        for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            p[i] = p[i - 1] * i;

        lock    = 1;
    }

    if(p_step >= p[n])
        return 0;

    char *pre, *post;
    pre     = malloc(11 * n * sizeof(char)); // I think these two are the trouble makers, maybe not
    post    = malloc(11 * n * sizeof(char));

    to_string(s, pre, n);

    int d = 1;
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        if(!(p_step % p[i]))
            d = i;

    if((n - d - 1) >= --m[d])
        m[d] = n - 1;

    swap(s, n - d - 1 , m[d]);

    to_string(s, post, n);

    p_step++;
    if(!strcmp(pre, post)) 
    {
        if(p_step >= p[n] - 1)
            return 0;
        next_permutation(n, s);
    }

    sort(s, n - d, n);

    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    char **s;
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    s = calloc(n, sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        s[i] = calloc(11, sizeof(char));
        scanf("%s", s[i]);
    }
    do
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            printf("%s%c", s[i], i == n - 1 ? '\n' : ' ');
    } while (next_permutation(n, s));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        free(s[i]);
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

```
$ ./a.out
6
a
b
c
d
e
f
a b c d e f
a.out: malloc.c:2379: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

```
pwndbg> run
Starting program: /home/TESTS/a.out 
6
a
b
c
d
e
f
a b c d e f
a.out: malloc.c:2379: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
50  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
LEGEND: STACK | HEAP | CODE | DATA | RWX | RODATA
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────[ REGISTERS ]───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 RAX  0x0
 RBX  0x7ffff7f96540 ◂— 0x7ffff7f96540
 RCX  0x7ffff7dea3eb (raise+203) ◂— mov    rax, qword ptr [rsp + 0x108]
 RDX  0x0
 RDI  0x2
 RSI  0x7fffffffd960 ◂— 0x0
 R8   0x0
 R9   0x7fffffffd960 ◂— 0x0
 R10  0x8
 R11  0x246
 R12  0x0
 R13  0x1000
 R14  0x555555559c00 ◂— 0x600000006
 R15  0x3
 RBP  0x50
 RSP  0x7fffffffd960 ◂— 0x0
 RIP  0x7ffff7dea3eb (raise+203) ◂— mov    rax, qword ptr [rsp + 0x108]
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────[ DISASM ]─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 ► 0x7ffff7dea3eb <raise+203>    mov    rax, qword ptr [rsp + 0x108]
   0x7ffff7dea3f3 <raise+211>    xor    rax, qword ptr fs:[0x28]
   0x7ffff7dea3fc <raise+220>    jne    raise+260 <0x7ffff7dea424>
    ↓
   0x7ffff7dea424 <raise+260>    call   __stack_chk_fail <0x7ffff7ed6dd0>

   0x7ffff7dea429                nop    dword ptr [rax]
   0x7ffff7dea430 <killpg>       endbr64 
   0x7ffff7dea434 <killpg+4>     test   edi, edi
   0x7ffff7dea436 <killpg+6>     js     killpg+16 <0x7ffff7dea440>

   0x7ffff7dea438 <killpg+8>     neg    edi
   0x7ffff7dea43a <killpg+10>    jmp    kill <0x7ffff7dea6e0>

   0x7ffff7dea43f <killpg+15>    nop    
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────[ STACK ]─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
00:0000│ rsi r9 rsp  0x7fffffffd960 ◂— 0x0
01:0008│             0x7fffffffd968 —▸ 0x7ffff7f959d8 —▸ 0x7ffff7fd0a06 ◂— 'GLIBC_PRIVATE'
02:0010│             0x7fffffffd970 —▸ 0x7ffff7ffd9e8 (_rtld_global+2440) —▸ 0x7ffff7fd0000 ◂— 0x10102464c457f
03:0018│             0x7fffffffd978 —▸ 0x7ffff7ffe4f0 —▸ 0x7ffff7ffe450 —▸ 0x7ffff7f95520 —▸ 0x7ffff7ffe190 ◂— ...
04:0020│             0x7fffffffd980 ◂— 0x0
05:0028│             0x7fffffffd988 —▸ 0x7ffff7dc8aa8 ◂— 0x1ea020
06:0030│             0x7fffffffd990 ◂— 0x7fff00000001
07:0038│             0x7fffffffd998 —▸ 0x7ffff7dc8ac0 ◂— 0x1ea018
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────[ BACKTRACE ]───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 ► f 0     7ffff7dea3eb raise+203
   f 1     7ffff7dc9899 abort+299
   f 2     7ffff7e3c4ba
   f 3     7ffff7e3eb0f sysmalloc+1855
   f 4     7ffff7e3f963 _int_malloc+3363
   f 5     7ffff7e41304 malloc+116
   f 6     555555555531 next_permutation+318
   f 7     5555555557dd main+283
   f 8     7ffff7dcb1e3 __libc_start_main+243
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Program received signal SIGABRT
pwndbg> backtrace
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
#1  0x00007ffff7dc9899 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007ffff7e3c4ba in __malloc_assert (assertion=assertion@entry=0x7ffff7f5f2d8 "(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)", file=file@entry=0x7ffff7f5b43f "malloc.c", line=line@entry=2379, function=function@entry=0x7ffff7f5fa60 <__PRETTY_FUNCTION__.13032> "sysmalloc") at malloc.c:298
#3  0x00007ffff7e3eb0f in sysmalloc (nb=nb@entry=80, av=av@entry=0x7ffff7f8eb80 <main_arena>) at malloc.c:2379
#4  0x00007ffff7e3f963 in _int_malloc (av=av@entry=0x7ffff7f8eb80 <main_arena>, bytes=bytes@entry=66) at malloc.c:4141
#5  0x00007ffff7e41304 in __GI___libc_malloc (bytes=66) at malloc.c:3058
#6  0x0000555555555531 in next_permutation (n=6, s=0x5555555596b0) at test.c:62
#7  0x00005555555557dd in main () at test.c:106
#8  0x00007ffff7dcb1e3 in __libc_start_main (main=0x5555555556c2 <main>, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffde78, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffde68) at ../csu/libc-start.c:308
#9  0x000055555555518e in _start ()
pwndbg>
```

```
$ valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all ./a.out
==23746== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==23746== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==23746== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==23746== Command: ./a.out
==23746== 
6
a
b
c
d
e
f
a b c d e f
==23746== Invalid write of size 4
==23746==    at 0x10947F: next_permutation (test.c:49)
==23746==    by 0x1097DC: main (test.c:106)
==23746==  Address 0x4a72b78 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 10 alloc'd
==23746==    at 0x483A7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==23746==    by 0x10944A: next_permutation (test.c:46)
==23746==    by 0x1097DC: main (test.c:106)
==23746== 
a b c d f e
==23746== Invalid write of size 4
==23746==    at 0x1095D6: next_permutation (test.c:72)
==23746==    by 0x1097DC: main (test.c:106)
==23746==  Address 0x4a72b78 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 10 alloc'd
==23746==    at 0x483A7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==23746==    by 0x10944A: next_permutation (test.c:46)
==23746==    by 0x1097DC: main (test.c:106)
==23746== 
==23746== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==23746==    at 0x1095DC: next_permutation (test.c:72)
==23746==    by 0x1097DC: main (test.c:106)
==23746== 
==23746== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==23746==    at 0x1092B1: swap (test.c:10)
==23746==    by 0x10962A: next_permutation (test.c:75)
==23746==    by 0x1097DC: main (test.c:106)
==23746== 
==23746== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==23746==    at 0x1092CF: swap (test.c:11)
==23746==    by 0x10962A: next_permutation (test.c:75)
==23746==    by 0x1097DC: main (test.c:106)
==23746== 
a b c e d f
a b c e f d
a b c f d e
a b c f e d
==23746== Invalid read of size 4
==23746==    at 0x1095D1: next_permutation (test.c:72)
==23746==    by 0x1097DC: main (test.c:106)
==23746==  Address 0x4a72b7c is 2 bytes after a block of size 10 alloc'd
==23746==    at 0x483A7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==23746==    by 0x10944A: next_permutation (test.c:46)
==23746==    by 0x1097DC: main (test.c:106)
==23746== 
==23746== Invalid read of size 4
==23746==    at 0x1095D8: next_permutation (test.c:72)
==23746==    by 0x1097DC: main (test.c:106)
==23746==  Address 0x4a72b7c is 2 bytes after a block of size 10 alloc'd
==23746==    at 0x483A7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==23746==    by 0x10944A: next_permutation (test.c:46)
==23746==    by 0x1097DC: main (test.c:106)
==23746== 
==23746== Invalid read of size 4
==23746==    at 0x109610: next_permutation (test.c:75)
==23746==    by 0x1097DC: main (test.c:106)
==23746==  Address 0x4a72b7c is 2 bytes after a block of size 10 alloc'd
==23746==    at 0x483A7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==23746==    by 0x10944A: next_permutation (test.c:46)
==23746==    by 0x1097DC: main (test.c:106)
==23746== 
a b d c e f
a b d c f e
==23746== Invalid write of size 4
==23746==    at 0x1095FA: next_permutation (test.c:73)
==23746==    by 0x1097DC: main (test.c:106)
==23746==  Address 0x4a72b78 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 10 alloc'd
==23746==    at 0x483A7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==23746==    by 0x10944A: next_permutation (test.c:46)
==23746==    by 0x1097DC: main (test.c:106)
==23746== 
a b d e c f
a b d e f c
a b d f c e
a b d f e c
a b e c d f
a b e c f d
a b e d c f
a b e d f c
a b e f c d
a b e f d c
a b f c d e
a b f c e d
a b f d c e
a b f d e c
a b f e c d
a b f e d c
a c b d e f
a c b d f e
a c b e d f
a c b e f d
a c b f d e
a c b f e d
a c d b e f
a c d b f e
a c d e b f
a c d e f b
a c d f b e
a c d f e b
a c e b d f
a c e b f d
a c e d b f
a c e d f b
a c e f b d
a c e f d b
a c f b d e
a c f b e d
a c f d b e
a c f d e b
a c f e b d
a c f e d b
a d b c e f
a d b c f e
a d b e c f
a d b e f c
a d b f c e
a d b f e c
a d c b e f
a d c b f e
a d c e b f
a d c e f b
a d c f b e
a d c f e b
a d e b c f
a d e b f c
a d e c b f
a d e c f b
a d e f b c
a d e f c b
a d f b c e
a d f b e c
a d f c b e
a d f c e b
a d f e b c
a d f e c b
a e b c d f
a e b c f d
a e b d c f
a e b d f c
a e b f c d
a e b f d c
a e c b d f
a e c b f d
a e c d b f
a e c d f b
a e c f b d
a e c f d b
a e d b c f
a e d b f c
a e d c b f
a e d c f b
a e d f b c
a e d f c b
a e f b c d
a e f b d c
a e f c b d
a e f c d b
a e f d b c
a e f d c b
a f b c d e
a f b c e d
a f b d c e
a f b d e c
a f b e c d
a f b e d c
a f c b d e
a f c b e d
a f c d b e
a f c d e b
a f c e b d
a f c e d b
a f d b c e
a f d b e c
a f d c b e
a f d c e b
a f d e b c
a f d e c b
a f e b c d
a f e b d c
a f e c b d
a f e c d b
a f e d b c
a f e d c b
b a c d e f
b a c d f e
b a c e d f
b a c e f d
b a c f d e
b a c f e d
b a d c e f
b a d c f e
b a d e c f
b a d e f c
b a d f c e
b a d f e c
b a e c d f
b a e c f d
b a e d c f
b a e d f c
b a e f c d
b a e f d c
b a f c d e
b a f c e d
b a f d c e
b a f d e c
b a f e c d
b a f e d c
b c a d e f
b c a d f e
b c a e d f
b c a e f d
b c a f d e
b c a f e d
b c d a e f
b c d a f e
b c d e a f
b c d e f a
b c d f a e
b c d f e a
b c e a d f
b c e a f d
b c e d a f
b c e d f a
b c e f a d
b c e f d a
b c f a d e
b c f a e d
b c f d a e
b c f d e a
b c f e a d
b c f e d a
b d a c e f
b d a c f e
b d a e c f
b d a e f c
b d a f c e
b d a f e c
b d c a e f
b d c a f e
b d c e a f
b d c e f a
b d c f a e
b d c f e a
b d e a c f
b d e a f c
b d e c a f
b d e c f a
b d e f a c
b d e f c a
b d f a c e
b d f a e c
b d f c a e
b d f c e a
b d f e a c
b d f e c a
b e a c d f
b e a c f d
b e a d c f
b e a d f c
b e a f c d
b e a f d c
b e c a d f
b e c a f d
b e c d a f
b e c d f a
b e c f a d
b e c f d a
b e d a c f
b e d a f c
b e d c a f
b e d c f a
b e d f a c
b e d f c a
b e f a c d
b e f a d c
b e f c a d
b e f c d a
b e f d a c
b e f d c a
b f a c d e
b f a c e d
b f a d c e
b f a d e c
b f a e c d
b f a e d c
b f c a d e
b f c a e d
b f c d a e
b f c d e a
b f c e a d
b f c e d a
b f d a c e
b f d a e c
b f d c a e
b f d c e a
b f d e a c
b f d e c a
b f e a c d
b f e a d c
b f e c a d
b f e c d a
b f e d a c
b f e d c a
c a b d e f
c a b d f e
c a b e d f
c a b e f d
c a b f d e
c a b f e d
c a d b e f
c a d b f e
c a d e b f
c a d e f b
c a d f b e
c a d f e b
c a e b d f
c a e b f d
c a e d b f
c a e d f b
c a e f b d
c a e f d b
c a f b d e
c a f b e d
c a f d b e
c a f d e b
c a f e b d
c a f e d b
c b a d e f
c b a d f e
c b a e d f
c b a e f d
c b a f d e
c b a f e d
c b d a e f
c b d a f e
c b d e a f
c b d e f a
c b d f a e
c b d f e a
c b e a d f
c b e a f d
c b e d a f
c b e d f a
c b e f a d
c b e f d a
c b f a d e
c b f a e d
c b f d a e
c b f d e a
c b f e a d
c b f e d a
c d a b e f
c d a b f e
c d a e b f
c d a e f b
c d a f b e
c d a f e b
c d b a e f
c d b a f e
c d b e a f
c d b e f a
c d b f a e
c d b f e a
c d e a b f
c d e a f b
c d e b a f
c d e b f a
c d e f a b
c d e f b a
c d f a b e
c d f a e b
c d f b a e
c d f b e a
c d f e a b
c d f e b a
c e a b d f
c e a b f d
c e a d b f
c e a d f b
c e a f b d
c e a f d b
c e b a d f
c e b a f d
c e b d a f
c e b d f a
c e b f a d
c e b f d a
c e d a b f
c e d a f b
c e d b a f
c e d b f a
c e d f a b
c e d f b a
c e f a b d
c e f a d b
c e f b a d
c e f b d a
c e f d a b
c e f d b a
c f a b d e
c f a b e d
c f a d b e
c f a d e b
c f a e b d
c f a e d b
c f b a d e
c f b a e d
c f b d a e
c f b d e a
c f b e a d
c f b e d a
c f d a b e
c f d a e b
c f d b a e
c f d b e a
c f d e a b
c f d e b a
c f e a b d
c f e a d b
c f e b a d
c f e b d a
c f e d a b
c f e d b a
d a b c e f
d a b c f e
d a b e c f
d a b e f c
d a b f c e
d a b f e c
d a c b e f
d a c b f e
d a c e b f
d a c e f b
d a c f b e
d a c f e b
d a e b c f
d a e b f c
d a e c b f
d a e c f b
d a e f b c
d a e f c b
d a f b c e
d a f b e c
d a f c b e
d a f c e b
d a f e b c
d a f e c b
d b a c e f
d b a c f e
d b a e c f
d b a e f c
d b a f c e
d b a f e c
d b c a e f
d b c a f e
d b c e a f
d b c e f a
d b c f a e
d b c f e a
d b e a c f
d b e a f c
d b e c a f
d b e c f a
d b e f a c
d b e f c a
d b f a c e
d b f a e c
d b f c a e
d b f c e a
d b f e a c
d b f e c a
d c a b e f
d c a b f e
d c a e b f
d c a e f b
d c a f b e
d c a f e b
d c b a e f
d c b a f e
d c b e a f
d c b e f a
d c b f a e
d c b f e a
d c e a b f
d c e a f b
d c e b a f
d c e b f a
d c e f a b
d c e f b a
d c f a b e
d c f a e b
d c f b a e
d c f b e a
d c f e a b
d c f e b a
d e a b c f
d e a b f c
d e a c b f
d e a c f b
d e a f b c
d e a f c b
d e b a c f
d e b a f c
d e b c a f
d e b c f a
d e b f a c
d e b f c a
d e c a b f
d e c a f b
d e c b a f
d e c b f a
d e c f a b
d e c f b a
d e f a b c
d e f a c b
d e f b a c
d e f b c a
d e f c a b
d e f c b a
d f a b c e
d f a b e c
d f a c b e
d f a c e b
d f a e b c
d f a e c b
d f b a c e
d f b a e c
d f b c a e
d f b c e a
d f b e a c
d f b e c a
d f c a b e
d f c a e b
d f c b a e
d f c b e a
d f c e a b
d f c e b a
d f e a b c
d f e a c b
d f e b a c
d f e b c a
d f e c a b
d f e c b a
e a b c d f
e a b c f d
e a b d c f
e a b d f c
e a b f c d
e a b f d c
e a c b d f
e a c b f d
e a c d b f
e a c d f b
e a c f b d
e a c f d b
e a d b c f
e a d b f c
e a d c b f
e a d c f b
e a d f b c
e a d f c b
e a f b c d
e a f b d c
e a f c b d
e a f c d b
e a f d b c
e a f d c b
e b a c d f
e b a c f d
e b a d c f
e b a d f c
e b a f c d
e b a f d c
e b c a d f
e b c a f d
e b c d a f
e b c d f a
e b c f a d
e b c f d a
e b d a c f
e b d a f c
e b d c a f
e b d c f a
e b d f a c
e b d f c a
e b f a c d
e b f a d c
e b f c a d
e b f c d a
e b f d a c
e b f d c a
e c a b d f
e c a b f d
e c a d b f
e c a d f b
e c a f b d
e c a f d b
e c b a d f
e c b a f d
e c b d a f
e c b d f a
e c b f a d
e c b f d a
e c d a b f
e c d a f b
e c d b a f
e c d b f a
e c d f a b
e c d f b a
e c f a b d
e c f a d b
e c f b a d
e c f b d a
e c f d a b
e c f d b a
e d a b c f
e d a b f c
e d a c b f
e d a c f b
e d a f b c
e d a f c b
e d b a c f
e d b a f c
e d b c a f
e d b c f a
e d b f a c
e d b f c a
e d c a b f
e d c a f b
e d c b a f
e d c b f a
e d c f a b
e d c f b a
e d f a b c
e d f a c b
e d f b a c
e d f b c a
e d f c a b
e d f c b a
e f a b c d
e f a b d c
e f a c b d
e f a c d b
e f a d b c
e f a d c b
e f b a c d
e f b a d c
e f b c a d
e f b c d a
e f b d a c
e f b d c a
e f c a b d
e f c a d b
e f c b a d
e f c b d a
e f c d a b
e f c d b a
e f d a b c
e f d a c b
e f d b a c
e f d b c a
e f d c a b
e f d c b a
f a b c d e
f a b c e d
f a b d c e
f a b d e c
f a b e c d
f a b e d c
f a c b d e
f a c b e d
f a c d b e
f a c d e b
f a c e b d
f a c e d b
f a d b c e
f a d b e c
f a d c b e
f a d c e b
f a d e b c
f a d e c b
f a e b c d
f a e b d c
f a e c b d
f a e c d b
f a e d b c
f a e d c b
f b a c d e
f b a c e d
f b a d c e
f b a d e c
f b a e c d
f b a e d c
f b c a d e
f b c a e d
f b c d a e
f b c d e a
f b c e a d
f b c e d a
f b d a c e
f b d a e c
f b d c a e
f b d c e a
f b d e a c
f b d e c a
f b e a c d
f b e a d c
f b e c a d
f b e c d a
f b e d a c
f b e d c a
f c a b d e
f c a b e d
f c a d b e
f c a d e b
f c a e b d
f c a e d b
f c b a d e
f c b a e d
f c b d a e
f c b d e a
f c b e a d
f c b e d a
f c d a b e
f c d a e b
f c d b a e
f c d b e a
f c d e a b
f c d e b a
f c e a b d
f c e a d b
f c e b a d
f c e b d a
f c e d a b
f c e d b a
f d a b c e
f d a b e c
f d a c b e
f d a c e b
f d a e b c
f d a e c b
f d b a c e
f d b a e c
f d b c a e
f d b c e a
f d b e a c
f d b e c a
f d c a b e
f d c a e b
f d c b a e
f d c b e a
f d c e a b
f d c e b a
f d e a b c
f d e a c b
f d e b a c
f d e b c a
f d e c a b
f d e c b a
f e a b c d
f e a b d c
f e a c b d
f e a c d b
f e a d b c
f e a d c b
f e b a c d
f e b a d c
f e b c a d
f e b c d a
f e b d a c
f e b d c a
f e c a b d
f e c a d b
f e c b a d
f e c b d a
f e c d a b
f e c d b a
f e d a b c
f e d a c b
f e d b a c
f e d b c a
f e d c a b
f e d c b a
==23746== 
==23746== HEAP SUMMARY:
==23746==     in use at exit: 110,599 bytes in 2,863 blocks
==23746==   total heap usage: 2,872 allocs, 9 frees, 112,761 bytes allocated
==23746== 
==23746== 10 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 6
==23746==    at 0x483A7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==23746==    by 0x10944A: next_permutation (test.c:46)
==23746==    by 0x1097DC: main (test.c:106)
==23746== 
==23746== 28 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 6
==23746==    at 0x483CD99: calloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==23746==    by 0x109428: next_permutation (test.c:44)
==23746==    by 0x1097DC: main (test.c:106)
==23746== 
==23746== 7,744 bytes in 704 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 6
==23746==    at 0x483A7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==23746==    by 0x109268: swap (test.c:7)
==23746==    by 0x109352: sort (test.c:20)
==23746==    by 0x1096BA: next_permutation (test.c:86)
==23746==    by 0x1097DC: main (test.c:106)
==23746== 
==23746== 7,909 bytes in 719 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 4 of 6
==23746==    at 0x483A7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==23746==    by 0x109268: swap (test.c:7)
==23746==    by 0x10962A: next_permutation (test.c:75)
==23746==    by 0x1097DC: main (test.c:106)
==23746== 
==23746== 47,454 bytes in 719 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 5 of 6
==23746==    at 0x483A7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==23746==    by 0x109530: next_permutation (test.c:62)
==23746==    by 0x1097DC: main (test.c:106)
==23746== 
==23746== 47,454 bytes in 719 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 6 of 6
==23746==    at 0x483A7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==23746==    by 0x10954C: next_permutation (test.c:63)
==23746==    by 0x1097DC: main (test.c:106)
==23746== 
==23746== LEAK SUMMARY:
==23746==    definitely lost: 110,561 bytes in 2,861 blocks
==23746==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23746==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23746==    still reachable: 38 bytes in 2 blocks
==23746==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23746== 
==23746== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==23746== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==23746== ERROR SUMMARY: 1598 errors from 13 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: I think you meant `(n+1) * sizeof(int)`

Comment: @r0bin_dood Operator precedence. `malloc(n + 1 * sizeof(int));` --> `malloc((n + 1) * sizeof(int));`

Comment: Multiplication has higher precedence, so `n + 1 * sizeof(int)` is the same as `n + sizeof(int)`

Comment: @user3386109 That's good catch by the way.

Comment: Yes I know, but I totally didn't think that was the problem, it completely flew over my head!!

Comment: The answer is in the first error message from valgrind. It tells you the line number where the memory was allocated (test.c:46), and the line number where the code writes past the end of the array (test.c:49).

Comment: Ooooooooh, I see, thank you so much!! This was such a headache for such a simple problem

Comment: You did a great job writing the question. It's not often that a question has all of the necessary information. Well done!

Comment: Am I the only one seeing that in the `swap()` routine, the return value from `malloc()` is thrown away on the second statement?

Comment: @SteveFriedl Good point, that should still show up in the leak report from valgrind.

Comment: This program appears to have major memory leaks all over it.

Comment: What is special about `11`?

Answer (score 2):

fixed by changing line,

from:

`m = malloc(n + 1 * sizeof(int));`

to

```
m = malloc((n + 1) * sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 2):

An additional point:

```
void swap(char **s, int a, int b) 
{
    char *t;
    t = malloc(11 * sizeof(char));

    t = s[a];    // Memory leak occurs at this point
    s[a] = s[b];
    s[b] = t;
}
```

The `malloc()` call allocates 11 bytes and assigns it to the `t` local variable, but *on the next line* that value is thrown away by assigning `s[a]` to it, and this is guaranteed to be a memory leak if `swap()` is ever called.